# How to resize this video using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Below is the code i am using. the video is displaying but can't resize it.
please help.

Html->media( 

                          array( 'MADE FOR FRIENDS.mp4', 

                          array( 'src' => 'MADE FOR FRIENDS.mp4', 'size'=>"100", 'type' => "video/ogg;codecs='theora, vorbis'")), 
                          array('autoplay')); ?>

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail, the code you included doesnt seem to be complete

Comment: "_cant resize it_" is not a proper problem description. Please be more specific as to what exactly you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp, there is no option for resize (i.e, size which you have used) in

```
 $this->Html->media();
```

So, it will display, but not resize. But still if you want to resize, you have to use some third party plugins.

Reference :[http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-videos-and-audio-files OR http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::media]